# SQL: External query is taking more time to fetch the result

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

When I run the query below it is taking more than a minute. But when I run the inner query it is executed with in a second. There are so many records in Orders table
Can someone please help me in improving the performance.

```
SELECT TOP (10) 
    [Filter1].[OrderID] AS [OrderID], 
    [Filter1].[ContactName] AS [ContactName]    
    FROM ( 
    SELECT [Extent1].[OrderID] AS [OrderID], 
    [Extent2].[ContactName] AS [ContactName], 
    row_number() OVER (ORDER BY [Extent1].[OrderID] ASC) AS [row_number]
        FROM  [dbo].[Orders] AS [Extent1]
        LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Customers] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[CustomerID] = [Extent2].[CustomerID]
        WHERE ( CAST(CHARINDEX(LOWER(N'ma'), LOWER([Extent2].[ContactName])) AS int)) > 0
    )  AS [Filter1]
    WHERE [Filter1].[row_number] > 10
    ORDER BY [Filter1].[OrderID] ASC
```

Comment: What happens if you remove the TOP and the ORDER BY? I'd guess that it's the sorting of the result set that's taking the time.

Comment: How many records?  Are you sure that the query is **completing** in a second?  Could it be that SSMS is just starting to display rows in that time?  Regardless, people will want to see the query plan, so please add that to your question.

Answer (score 0):

To improve the performance create `index`on your orders table. Getting Top 10  and then ordering the inner query results will take time as it doubles the time with order by either remove order by or top 10 if its not compulsory or best option use index on Orders(orderid) to perform ordering via fast index search selection.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with CTE ? are you trying to achieve 11th to 20th row ? top 10 row where row_number > 10

```
; WITH ordercte AS
          (

     SELECT  [Extent1].[OrderID] AS [OrderID], 
    [Extent2].[ContactName] AS [ContactName], 
    row_number() OVER (ORDER BY [Extent1].[OrderID] ASC) AS [row_number]
        FROM  [dbo].[Orders] AS [Extent1]
        LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Customers] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[CustomerID] = [Extent2].[CustomerID]
        WHERE ( CAST(CHARINDEX(LOWER(N'ma'), LOWER([Extent2].[ContactName])) AS int)) > 0
          )

          SELECT OrderID,ContactName FROM ordercte WHERE row_number > 10 ORDER BY OrderID ASC
```